# What datatype should I save for hh:mm tt in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a web form that has a dropdownlist with hh:mm tt with 30 minutes interval, starting from 6:00am, 6:30 am, 7:00am....8:00pm. How can I save selected time into SQL Server? I am not sure what datatype (`Date`, `DateTime`, `Time(7)`) in SQL Server I should use.

Please help me advise.

This is my C# code to load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddDropDownValues(ref ddlHrMin, 6, 20, 30);
}
```

This is how I defined to come out as this hh:mm tt

```
 private void AddDropDownValues(ref DropDownList ddlHrMin, int startHour, int endHour, int increment)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime startTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, startHour, 0, 0);
    DateTime endTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, endHour, 0, 0);

    while (startTime <= endTime)
    {
        ddlHrMin.Items.Add(startTime.ToShortTimeString());
        startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(increment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Datetime. There really should be no debate or thinking about this. If you store datetime data put it in a datetime datatype.

Comment: If selected data is 6:30am, how would it save in table?

Comment: If you are using newer versions of sql, you can use the time datatype. `select cast(getdate() as time)`

Comment: I almost always use unix timestamps. I take an int(11). Easy sorting... Takes very low space.. I don't have a reason why you can't use it. Format the date when displaying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple options here. One is the built-in [Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) type. This is the preferred type, but it can be awkward to use with client code. It's also not available with Sql Server 2005 and older. Since you're working with 30 minute intervals, another option is an `int` indicating the number of intervals since midnight, or the number of minutes since midnight. The trick here is that you have to write code to transform inputs and outputs. You could also use a DateTime, though this can be overkill if you're not looking at a specific day, and only care about the time portion.

The one thing you definitely want to avoid is storing this data as a string.